# (Slightly) Different reputation level on Meta and the main site

Tags: discussion, support, reputation, reputation-history

I recently noticed that I have one more reputation on Meta than the main Stack Overflow site:

Stack Overflow: <kbd>[image]</kbd>

Meta: <kbd>[image]</kbd>

Is there a reason for this reputation difference?

I originally thought the reputation was synced across from Stack Overflow to Meta, or is there a snag here that I haven't found out?

Comment: The cache hasn't expired on Meta yet.  Give it time.

Comment: [It's not working! Should I blame caching?](http://shouldiblamecaching.com)